# Удаления записей в таблице MySQL

Tags: php

Делаю такой запрос :

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM message WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Но он ничего не делает, и еще нужно чтоб все записи удаляло, подскажите пожалуйста ошибку

Comment: правда у тебя есть таблица message?


Правда ты точно знаешь что передается $_SESSION['username']?

Comment: там все точно есть

Comment: Если всё есть, то ты где-то явно перемудрил. Чудес-то ведь не бывает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос в переменную:`$q="DELETE FROM message WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'";`
Делаем дамп или просто выводим print'ом. Вводим свой запрос в mysqld либо PMA и смотрим ответ сервера. Пишем его сюда

Comment: B что это типа правильный ответ?
ппц. я с вас торчу!

Comment: Да это-же прикол, чему тут удивляться то =)

Comment: ахах!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ну тогда так

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM message WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."' LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
```

Если не поможет, тогда var_dump($_SESSION) в студию

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM message WHERE username='$username'")or die(mysql_error());
```